# Conformal map from a 7-sided polyhedron to a square pyramid.

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, analyticity, analytic-functions

I have a right-angled square pyramid, $A$, whose height and base-length is $l$. By 'right-angled', I mean that the apex of $A$ lies vertically above one of the vertices in its base. Now supposed I form a new polyhedron, $B$, by gluing a cube with side-length is $l$ to the base of $A$ ($B$ now has a base-length $l$ and height $2l$). Additionally, suppose that I have a new pyramid $A^{'}$ that is similar to $A$, but with a height and base-length of $2l$.

Does anyone know how to derive a conformal map from the interior of $B$ to that of $A^{'}$?

P.s. I have also cross-posted this on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350214/conformal-map-from-a-7-sided-polyhedron-to-a-square-pyramid

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Conformal map from a 7-sided polyhedron to a square pyramid](https://mathoverflow.net/q/350214). In such cases, it is recommended to link each of the copies to the other ones. See  [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) (and other posts related to [meta-tag:cross-posting] on meta).

Comment: Thanks so much! I was not aware of this, as I am relatively new to SE.